# Как исправить ошибку с версией php в Open Server?

Tags: composer, php7, openserver

Для проекта необходима версия  "php": "^7.1.3", у меня была установлена в модулях 7.0.14 в версии 5.2.2.0 Пришлось скачать OS версию 5.2.8 В модулях выбран php 7.2*64 Apache 7.2*62 В phpinfo также инфа о том, что версия 7.2

Но при запуске команды composer update в корне проекта

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - This package requires php ^7.1.3 but your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - laravel/framework v5.7.9 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement. и т.д.

В параметрах был изменен путь и версия php: Компьютер -> Свойство системы -> Дополнительный параметры -> "Дополнительно : Переменная среда" В системных переменных найти "Path" D:\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP-7.2*64 Но в cmd теперь
ругается на отсутствие кучи библиотек типа
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mbstring.dll' (tried: w:/modules/php/PHP-7.2-x64/ext/php_mbstring.dll (▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒.
), w:/modules/php/PHP-7.2-x64/ext/php_php_mbstring.dll.dll (▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒.
)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_bz2.dll' (tried: w:/modules/php/PHP-7.2-x64/ext/php_bz2.dll (▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒.
), w:/modules/php/PHP-7.2-x64/ext/php_php_bz2.dll.dll (▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒.
)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_curl.dll' (tried: w:/modules/php/PHP-7.2-x64/ext/php_curl.dll (▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒.
), w:/modules/php/PHP-7.2-x64/ext/php_php_curl.dll.dll (▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒

А также

> [Composer\Exception\NoSslException]
>     The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not available. If you can not enable the openssl ex
>     tension, you can disable this error, at your own risk, by setting the 'disable-tls' option to true.

В config php 7.2  эти extension имеются и без знаков ";"

Answer (score 0):

1 Создать папку ext в модулях, к примеру:

```
D:\Open Server\OSPanel\modules\php\ext
```

2 В папку ext перенести все dll из текущей версии php

3 В config (D:\OSold\OpenServer\userdata\config) изменить относительные пути т.к. Apache не понимает относительные пути php.ini в системах Windows.

```
extension_dir="C:\full\path\to\php\ext"
```